# Integral (kernel) operator on L1 space with (non-sigma finite measure)

Tags: measure-theory, operator-theory, banach-spaces

Suppose $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ and $(Y,\Gamma,\nu)$ are measure spaces, and especially **not** sigma finite. Consider some measurable set $C\in\Sigma\otimes\Gamma$ and the corresponding characteritic function on $X\times Y$, say $1_{C}$. Suppose know that the operator from $E:=L_{1}(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ into $F:=L_{1}(Y,\Gamma,\nu)$ defined by $T:E\rightarrow F$, $(Tf)(y):=\int_{X}1_{C}(x,y) f(x)d\mu$ is a linear bounded operator. Now what can we conclude from the set $C$, is it possible that
$\mu\otimes\nu(C)=\infty$. If for example $C=A\times B$ is a rectangle, then either $A$ or $B$ must have finite measure, since $T$ is bounded.

Answer (score 0):

If $ C= A\times B$ then $1_C(x,y) = 1_A(x) 1_B(y)$ and therefore :
$$(Tf)(y) = 1_B(y) \int_A f\text d\mu$$

Therefore :
$$\|Tf\|_1 = \nu(B)\left|\int_A f\text d\mu\right|$$

If $\nu(B)<+\infty$, then $T$ is bounded (without any assumption on $A$ beyond measurability). Conversely, $C = A\times B$ is a rectangle, $T$ is bounded and there is $f \in L^1(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ with $\int_A f\text d\mu  \neq 0$, then $\nu(B)<+\infty$. This last condition is satisfied if $A$ contains a measurable set whose measure is not zero or infinity.

In particular, it is possible that $\mu\otimes \nu(C)  = +\infty$.

Comment: Thank you @SolubleFish, what do u exactly mean with "converse"? In particular, can u give an example of "C", not necessarily an rectangle?

Comment: You can take $C$ to be any member of the product $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma \otimes \Gamma$. I am not sure what kind of example you want.

Comment: I mean $C$ for wich the measure is infinite, especially not a countable union of sets of finite measure. So $C\neq\BigCup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}C_n$ with $C_n$ finite measure.

Comment: Take $B$ with finite measure, $A = X$ not $\sigma$-finite. Then, $C=  A\times B$ is not $\sigma$-finite, but $T$ is bounded. From this you can manufacture similar examples where $C$ is not a rectangle.